# How could I make this code run faster and smoother?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Three issues.

This code is running in 4-5 minutes for me with the database that I currently have. Normally it will be a database with 100~ columns. I want to make this faster.

Another issue I have is that I keep getting two different pop-ups:

1. "File now Available for Editing"

[image: read-write]

2. "User is currently editing workbook, would you like to run in read-only mode?"

[image: read-only]

Very annoying, but nothing I can't live with.

Lastly, I also sometimes get an error on this line: 
`pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse` But all I have to do is re-run the program and it'll go away.

I'm looking for any suggestions to make this code run a little faster and smoother, any recommendations are welcome.

Thanks!

```
Public Sub averageScoreRelay()
    ' 1. Run from PPT and open an Excel file
    ' 2. Start at slide 1 and find a box that contains the words "iq_", if it has those words then it will have numbers after it like so "iq_43" or "iq_43, iq_56,iq_72".
    ' 3. find those words and numbers in the opened Excel file after splitting and re-formating string.
    ' 3. Copy column into a new sheets and repeat for all "iq_'s" until sheets 2 has a table.
    ' 4. Copy table from xl Paste Table into ppt
    ' 5. Do this for every slide



'Timer start
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
        StartTime = Timer   

'Create variables   
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim Shpe As Shape
    Dim pptText As String
    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim iq_Array As Variant
    Dim arrayLoop As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myShape As Object
    Dim colNumb As Integer
    Dim size As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim lCols As Long

    ' Create new excel instance and open relevant workbook
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    'xlApp.Visible = True 'Make Excel visible
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("file.xlsx", True, False, , , , True, Notify:=False) 'Open relevant workbook
    If xlWB Is Nothing Then ' may not need this if statement. check later.
        MsgBox ("Error retrieving Average Score Report, Check file path")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    With xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        colNumb = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    'Create a new blank Sheet in excel, should be "Sheet2"

    xlWB.Worksheets.Add After:=xlWB.ActiveSheet

    'Make pptPres the ppt active
    Set pptPres = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation

    'Loop through each pptSlide and check for IQ text box, grab avgScore values and create pptTable
    For Each pptSlide In pptPres.Slides
        pptSlide.Select

        'searches through shapes in the slide
        For Each Shpe In pptSlide.Shapes

            k = 1

            'Identify if there is text frame
            If Shpe.HasTextFrame Then

                'Identify if there's text in text frame
                If Shpe.TextFrame.HasText Then

                    'Set pptText as the Text in the box, then make it lowercase and trim Spaces and Enters
                    pptText = Shpe.TextFrame.TextRange
                    pptText = LCase(Replace(pptText, " ", vbNullString))
                    pptText = Replace(Replace(Replace(pptText, vbCrLf, vbNullString), vbCr, vbNullString), vbLf, vbNullString)


                    'Identify if within text there is "iq_"
                    If InStr(1, pptText, "iq_") > 0 Then

                        'set iq_Array as an array of the split iq's
                        iq_Array = Split(pptText, ",")

                        'Find size of the array
                        size = UBound(iq_Array) - LBound(iq_Array)

                        'loop for each iq_ in the array'
                        For arrayLoop = 0 To size

                        'Statement that will take iq_'s in the form "iq_9" or "iq_99" or "iq_999"
                        If iq_Array(arrayLoop) Like "iq_#" Or iq_Array(arrayLoop) Like "iq_##" Or iq_Array(arrayLoop) Like "iq_###" Then

                            'loops for checking each column
                            For i = 1 To colNumb

                                'Copies the first column (role column) for every slide that needs it
                                If i = 1 And arrayLoop = 0 Then

                                    'copy column
                                    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy

                                    'paste column in Sheet2 which was newly created
                                    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(1)

                                'If this is not the role column, then check to see if the iq_'s match from ppt to xl
                                ElseIf xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i) = iq_Array(arrayLoop) And i <> 1 Then

                                    'Serves to paste in the next column of Sheet2 so that we end up with a table
                                    k = k + 1

                                    'same as above
                                    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).Copy
                                    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(k)

                                    'Go to next array
                                    GoTo Line2
                                End If
                            Next i

                        'Same as above, just this one is for iq_'s with form "iq_45,46,47" instead of "iq_45,iq_46,iq_47"
                        ElseIf (iq_Array(0) Like "iq_#" Or iq_Array(0) Like "iq_##" Or iq_Array(0) Like "iq_###") And (IsNumeric(iq_Array(arrayLoop)) And Len(iq_Array(arrayLoop)) <= 3) Then
                            For i = 1 To colNumb
                                If i = 1 And arrayLoop = 0 Then
                                    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy
                                    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(1)
                                ElseIf xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i) = ("iq_" & iq_Array(arrayLoop)) And i <> 1 Then 'if iq in ppt = iq in xl and if not the first cell then execute
                                    k = k + 1
                                    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).Copy
                                    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(k)
                                    GoTo Line2
                                End If
                            Next i
                        End If

Line2:

                        Next arrayLoop
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next Shpe

    'calculate last row and last column on sheet2. aka. find Table size
    With xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        lRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lCols = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'If only one column then go to next slide
        If lRows = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlUp).Row And lCols = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToLeft).Column Then
            GoTo Line1
        End If

            'Copy table
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRows, lCols)).Copy
    End With

            'Paste Table into ppt
            pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse

            'Recently pasted shape is the last shape on slide, so it will be the same as count of shapes on slide
            Set myShape = pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count)

            'Set position:
            myShape.Left = -200
            myShape.Top = 200

            'Clear Sheet2 for next slide
            xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:P10").Clear

Line1:

    Next pptSlide

    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
    xlWB.Close
    xlApp.Quit

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

    'End Timer
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
        MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what is the error you're getting on `pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse`? Make *this* question specifically about it, get it fixed, and then you'll have a great post for [codereview.se], where people review code that **works as intended**, making it "faster and smoother", easier to read, maintain, and debug.

Comment: @Mat's Mug I will update it once I can reproduce it! Thank you :)